# Installing a Graphic User Interface in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: lxde, arm, enlightenment, icewm

I have install Ubuntu 14.04 LTS in an ARM device, but it comes without a Graphic User Interface. In another ARM device I managed to install a GUI (Ubuntu Desktop), but this device has less internal memory and can not be installed. So I have been looking for other alternatives such as LXDE, Enlightenment or Icewm. However in tutorials I have been looking for seems that the repositories needed are outdated.

For example while installing Enlightenment I get this error:

```
package enlightenment has not installation candidate
```

Then, when the installation of Icewn goes good, but when I try to lunch Icewm with `sudo icewm` I get this error:

```
$ sudo icewm
IceWM: using /home/ubuntu/.icewm for private configuration files
IceWM: Can't open display: <none>. X must be running and $DISPLAY set.
```

I don´t know why, my ARM device is connected to a VGA display.

Comment: What tutorial are you using for installation? It appears that you are missing several steps

Comment: Thanks for answering Mostafa. 

This tutorial for Enlightenment:

http://www.noobslab.com/2017/05/install-enlightenment-e21-desktop-in.html

This is the tutorial I am using for Icewm:

https://www.howtoinstall.co/es/ubuntu/trusty/icewm

Comment: See. The error `package enlightenment has not installation candidate` means either there is no installation package in repositories or you haven't updated it yet. Make sure you have added PPA and ran `sudo apt updated`.

Comment: Thank again for answering. I will try to seek for another ppa. However I am more interesed in Icewm, do you know something about that error?

Comment: For errors you get for icewm, it seems you don't have Xorg which is the most essential one for having GUI. Simply run `sudo apt install xorg`

Comment: Thanks Mostafa. I tried the sudo apt install xorg with no positive results. I get the same error.

Comment: Thank you Mostafa. You finally save my day. Thanks is solved.

Comment: Good :). I send the solution as an answer. Please approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error regarding `package enlightenment has not installation candidate` means either there is no package in the already installed repositories or you haven't updated them. So you need to either add the relevant PPA or updating your local database using `apt update`.

The second error clearly shows there is no Xorg on your system. So, simply install it using:

```
sudo apt install xorg
```